# Модульнуе тестирование в yii2: тестирование моделей

Tags: юнит-тесты, yii2, phpunit

Здравствуйте. Решил писать приложение на yii2 через unit тесты. Возникли следующие вопросы:

```
class UsersTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
   /**
    * @var \UnitTester
    */
    protected $users;

    protected function _before()
    {
        $this->users = new \app\models\Users;
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testGeId()
    {

    }

}
```

Как видно, пытаюсь подключить модель Users, при этом вылетает ошибка о том, что данный класс не найден. В чем проблема, почему класс не может быть найден?

Не могу понять, для чего нужен yii2-faker и для чего нужно создавать базу `yii2_basic_tests`. Где о них можно прочесть?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Etki, есть след. код:

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалось в том, что не был создан экземпляр самого приложения при запуске тестов. tests/_bootstrap.php должен содержать след. код:

```
require('/../vendor/autoload.php');
require('/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require('config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config));
```

Подробности [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2627)

P.S.: [@Etki](/users/16095/etki), отдельное спасибо, подсказал куда копать.

Comment: а у меня такой _bootstrap https://gist.github.com/des1roer/52e44c25b760f6681389 и все равно не работает

Answer (score 1):

1. Наверняка надо подключить `vendor/autoload.php`. С `yii2-codeception` я не работал, но судя по родительскому классу, он здесь не используется.
2. Модели, как правило, не нужно тестировать. Тестироваться должен нижележащий слой (active record), сами модели должны просто его использовать.

**Обновление**

Если у вас метод отсеивает три записи, то его тестировать не нужно. Если у вас что-то серьезное, то это должно быть вынесено на уровень выше.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, Active record уже протестированный (я полагаю) разработчиками. Модели приходится тестировать, туда же часто приходится вписывать свои методы.

Comment: @Etki, я был бы вам очень признателен если бы вы дали конкретики. Вы меня заинтриговали. Спасибо.

Comment: vendor/autoload.php подключен во входном скрипте.

Comment: @z_coder, у меня пока не было времени ознакомиться с тестированием yii2. Конкретно с codeception vendor/autoload.php должен подключаться в файле tests/_bootstrap.php, он идет в обход основного скрипта.

Comment: @Etki, в tests/_bootstrap.php также подключается vendor/autoload.php

Comment: @z_coder а такая строчка есть?

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');